# Google Analytics showing real time visitors, but none in Audience report since using CloudFlare

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, real-time, cdn, cloudflare

First of all i'd like to say i really like CloudFlare!

The only thing i cannot get my head around is that Google Analytics does not show any visits in the Audience report. While it DOES show real time visitors.

The Audience report from yesterday shows me 0 visits while in real time i could see around 10 active visitors at any given time.

I have looked for a solution for hours now but cannot find anything regarding this matter.

Screenshot at http://srwww.eu/forumattachments/cloudflare-google-analytics.png

**Solved**
Solved "itself" within 24 hours. It seems there was a delay in the reporting.
Not sure if the delay was caused by Google Analytics or CloudFlare.

Comment: GA is your culprit for sure, not cloudflare. All standard and custom reports in the free version of Google Analytics are delayed by some amount, sometimes up to many hours. Only the real-time reporting shows you real-time data. Even if the data has shown up in the real-time report, does not mean it will then be visible straight away in the standard reports such as Audience.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics' processing latency is 24-48 hours, with higher usage increasing this delay. To quote [Google's Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency):

> Processing latency is up to 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more
>   than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports
>   being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and
>   metrics for up to two days.

There's also further information on this "hits to Answers delay" ratio on [another Help page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084038?hl=en#about). Essentially the more hits you have, the longer your results will be delayed!

If you have just passed a threshold, you may notice a sudden increase in delay.